# Does Oracle persist Java Calendar into TIMESTAMP with timezone?

Tags: java, oracle, calendar, timezone, timestamp

We are persisting a Java Calendar object into an Oracle TIMESTAMP column using the `getTimeInMillis()` method.  Does Oracle persist this data with a time zone?

I'm assuming not as we are not using the TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE data type.  If not, when you query `SELECT MY_TIMESTAMP FROM MYTABLE` what timezone will Oracle associate with this field?

And what is the correct way to 'cast' this to the timezone you are interested in (ie: UTC)?

Answer (score 0):

> `getTimeInMillis()`

is independent of the calendar system and the timezone. So in whichever timezone you specify the time in, the time is not gonna vary and `getTimeInMillis()` will get the accurate time.

> And on the persistence -

yes the oracle persist the data with the timezone. But it will add the timezone offset to the value saved.

> So that's brings us to the next question of choosing the right
>   timezone -

it is ideal to choose the native timezone. As this scenario is a combination of oracle and java its best to use UTC

Cheers!

Comment: Does Oracle persist the timezone with TIMESTAMP data type?   Or only with TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE data type?